# IOS App - Metodo applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, swift, app

Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación en IOS y quiero que cuando se actualiza mi bbdd (Firebase) en el método del asunto (applicationDidEnterBackground) me llegue una notificación para mostrarla en el icono de mi app.

Tengo este código:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

       - Llamada a Firebase (funciona correctamente cuando se actualiza un nodo)

       - UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    }

}
```

El código está bien, tanto la llamada a firebase como las notificaciones (probadas), mi problema viene de que este código cuando la aplicación entra en background no funciona y no se el motivo.

Es más, si vuelvo a entrar en la app, es cuando el código por fin se ejecuta y me pone la notificación en el icono de la app.

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes varios ejemplos de como continuar ejecutando en segundo plano:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html